# Bind Dictionary to ItemsControl in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, itemscontrol

I'm trying to bind KeyValuePair Elements from a Dictionary to a ItemsControl.
My Dictionary has 15 Elements and the following code shows me 15 TextBoxes:

```
<WrapPanel Name="PersonsWrapPanel" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto">
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value.Text}"></TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</WrapPanel>
```

Unfortunately without any TextBox content (which would be Key or Value).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using this line:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
```

The code on http://www.dev102.com/2008/03/07/binding-a-wpf-control-to-a-dictionary/ doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try binding directly to the values of the dictionary:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Persons.Values}"
```

If I am understanding your XAML properly, each object in the dictionary has a field called "Text" to which you are trying to bind.  If so and you make the above changes, you will need to change your DataTemplate as well:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

See [this article](http://www.dev102.com/2008/03/07/binding-a-wpf-control-to-a-dictionary/) for more info.  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have a Dictionary called RowValues, with both the [key, value] defined as [string, string].

Now to bind to the Value Pair of this dictionary, you can do the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RowValues.Values}" >
```

To display the text (Value), you can bind as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
```